# carry over effect

Tags: model, generalized-estimating-equations

When testing the carry-over effect (period*treatment) for cross-validation by GEE, do I actually need to bring in the main factors period, and treatment to the GEE model?

(1) Y = intercept + (period*treatment)X + residual
(2) Y = intercept + (Period)X1 + (treatment)X2 + (period*treatment)X3 + residual

Which model is the appropriate one?

Thank you for helping out.